# Do guest characters gain AP during battle?

Tags: final-fantasy-tactics, final-fantasy-tactics-advance

I'm playing the mission in which Ritz makes her appearance. Her clan member died and I'm not sure whether I should bother reviving her or not in the case she may gain AP and join my roster.

Comment: Just commenting as I may not remember correctly, but I don't think that Ritz clan members join you.

Comment: It has been ages since I played this game, but I think you can recruit her and her "sidekick" by doing side quests; however, I doubt that what ever they do as guests will matter when you recruit them. Also, why is the original tactics tagged? That game has an incredibly different system than the advanced version and I'm not sure this question applies.

Comment: @Leon7C I guess I figured an answer for the original series, lacking one for advance, is better than no answer at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guest characters don't gain AP during battle. Even if they do according to the game mechanics, they are likely only temporary and any gains are lost upon completion of the quest, as their stats are always pre-defined when joining your clan.

Additionally, only Ritz and Shara will join you, both of whom will offer to join you on... [spoiler]

> separate occasions upon the completion of the specific quest they star in. These two said quests appear after completing the main storyline.

At no point in the game will you recruit a character who mentions or implys they were once fighting alongside Ritz. The random name generator that kicks in when you encounter random new recruits upon the completion of side quests may generate the same name as one of the members in Ritz's clan during the main storyline, but that would be entirely coincidental.